# Ruby on Rails model reuse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, orm, model, relationship

I'm quite new to RoR.

Just to be short: Guest should be able to leave a **Review** for the Property he stayed in; Property is being owned by the Host. Host should able to leave a review for the Guest (Guest stayed in the host's Property). I don't think that it is wise to have two separate models (like, ReviewToHost, ReviewToGuest) for that - so it would be nice, if @property.reviews and @user.reviews worked with a single Review model. Is there a solution for that ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: polymorphism should fit your needs

Comment: This [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) should tell you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Make review as polymorphic,You can watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: Although I have already received the same answer, thanks to you too!!